# How to specify additional include directories for msbuild.exe

Tags: node.js, msbuild, npm, node-gyp

I am attempting to install the nodejs module ibm_db. The issue I am having is that in order to install this module node-gyp needs to build it using msbuild, but it won't detect some header files I have installed.

How do I add the directory of my additional header files to some path so hatt msbuild.exe will find them when trying to compile any project? On linux I simply set cpath= and everything build just fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSBuild exposes special properties for resolving references in build time.
You can set `AssemblySearchPaths` and `AdditionalLibPaths`.

E.g. `msbuild your.sln /p:AssemblySearchPaths="C:\Dev\Lib\Foo;C:\Dev\Lib\Bar;"`

See [Common MSBuild Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx)

Comment: What about include paths?